# Scaling linestrings gives incorrected final scale

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, scale, affine-transformation

I have a shapefile with about 5000 line strings. I am translating and scaling this file using `GeoPandas`:

```
import geopandas

green = geopandas.read_file('./shapefiles/unnamed (1)_green.shp')
```

The translation process completes with no problem but the scaling projects wrong coordinates.

Translating:

```
green['geometry'].translate(510959.95011, 3935297.77119)
```

[image]

Scaling:

```
green['geometry'] = green['geometry'].scale(2,2,2)
```

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use `origin` parameter, a geometry is scaled from its bounding box center. Therefore, use an appropriate center coordinate for `origin`.

For example:

```
green['geometry'].scale(2, 2, origin=(510959.95011, 3935297.77119))
```